# Issues with try/except, attempting to convert strings to integers in pandas data frame where possible

Tags: python, pandas, try-except

I made a function to clean up any HTML code/tags from strings in my dataframe. The function takes every value from the data frame, cleans it with the remove_html function, and returns a clean df. After converting the data frame to string values and cleaning it up I'm attempting to convert where possible the values in the data frame back to integers. I have tried try/except but don't get the result that I want. This is what I have at the moment:

```
def clean_df(df):
    df = df.astype(str)
    list_of_columns = list(df.columns)
    for col in list_of_columns:
        column = []
        for row in list(df[col]):
            column.append(remove_html(row))
            try:
                return int(row)
            except ValueError:
                pass

        del df[col]

        df[col] = column

    return df
```

Without the try/except statements the function returns a clean df where the integers are strings. So its just the try/except statement that seems to be an issue. I've tried the try/except statements in multiple ways and none of them return a df. The current code for example returns an 'int' object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works like this:

```
def clean_df(df):
df = df.astype(str)
list_of_columns = list(df.columns)
for col in list_of_columns:
    column = []
    for row in list(df[col]):
        try:
            column.append(int(remove_html(row)))
        except ValueError:
            column.append(remove_html(row))

    del df[col]

    df[col] = column

return df
```

Answer (score 2):

insert the `columm.append` into the `try:`

```
for col in list_of_columns:
    column = []
    for row in list(df[col]):
        try:
            column.append(remove_html(row))
        except ValueError:
            pass

    del df[col]

    df[col] = column

return df
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately this returns an int object and not a df.

Comment: well you are telling your code to `return int(row)`, I took it out of  your initial code..

Answer (score 0):

consider the `pd.DataFrame` `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, '2', '_', '4']))
```

[image]

You want to use the function `pd.to_numeric`...
***Note***
`pd.to_numeric` operates on scalars and `pd.Series`.  It doesn't operate on a `pd.DataFrame`
***Also***
Use the parameter `errors='coerce'` to get numbers where you can and `NaN` elsewhere.

```
pd.to_numeric(df['A'], 'coerce')

0    1.0
1    2.0
2    NaN
3    4.0
Name: A, dtype: float6
```

Or, to get numbers where you can, and what you already had elsewhere

```
pd.to_numeric(df['A'], 'coerce').combine_first(df['A'])

0    1
1    2
2    _
3    4
Name: A, dtype: object
```

you can then assign it back to your `df`

```
df['A'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], 'coerce').combine_first(df['A'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the try/except in a function and use that function with [`DataFrame.applymap()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a','b','1'],
                   ['2','c','d'],
                   ['e','3','f']])
def foo(thing):
    try:
        return int(thing)
    except ValueError as e:
        return thing

>>> df[0][2]
'e'
>>> df[0][1]
'2'
>>> df = df.applymap(foo)
>>> df[0][2]
'e'
>>> df[0][1]
2
>>>
```